# play alert song every 5 minutes even when app is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I tried to show a toast every 5 minutes and play a alert song, but it is not working, nothing happens.

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

..

<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

MainActivity:

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 5 minutes.
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 5, alarmIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(context, "OnReceive alarm test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

any ideas if something is missing or if something is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[`setRepeating`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is functionally deprecated (since api 19) in favor of [`setInexactRepeating`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) which has minimum interval of 15 minutes and may add extra delay when batching multiple alarms.

If You want such aggressive alarm you'll need to use one-shot [`setExact`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) alarm and re-schedule next one in `onReceive`.

Comment: Thank you, friend. I will try it!